# If someone already has children and then has a child with someone who has never had children before, is that child a firstborn?

Tags: bechor-firstborn

If someone had their first kid with a person who had children from a previous marriage, is that child a firstborn?

Comment: Firstborn for what purpose? It will likely matter.

Comment: If this is a real situation please make sure to speak with a qualified rabbi about the details of your particular situation when receiving a final ruling.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28356/5

Comment: Not real situation Just hypothetical, but I'm sure it can apply to some. An example of use would be Pidyon Haben

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a summary of an answer via wikipedia

The firstborn of one's mother is referred to in the Bible (Exodus 13:2) as one who "opens the womb" of his mother. Therefore, the firstborn of the father exclusively, although considered as a firstborn regarding his father's inheritance, is not considered as a firstborn regarding the requirement to be redeemed, as the mother's womb has already been opened by his half-sibling, the firstborn of his mother. Thus, the [Shulchan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firstborn_%28Judaism%29#cite_ref-7) Aruch rules that only a first born of the mother is required to be redeemed.

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch. Translated by Rabbi Avrohom Davis. Metsudah Publishers, 1996. P. 717